# How to delete a JSON element by index?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to delete the first element from a JSON object. Say that I have this:

```
var thing = {property:'something', does:'somethingElse', is:'somethingCool'};
var thing2 = {does:'somethingElse', property:'something', is:'somethingCool'}
```

I need a function that would remove 'property' from thing and 'somethingElse' from thing2 (whatever is at index 0; the first item).

I tried the following:

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
delete person[0];
console.log(person);
```

But it does not work.

Seems straight forward enough but I just can't seem to find the answer online.

Comment: Object properties are not ordered so there’s no guarantee what the first property will be.

Comment: Hey thanks for getting involved in the StackOverflow community. @mark-meyer is right on this one. Javascript objects do not contain order and cannot be referenced by their order in the way you are describing. If you want to use something to store some data that has order, you might consider using an array but in your case it seems that you are dealing with objects. Would you be able to explain why you need to remove a property based on order?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with Object.keys()

```
let keys = Object.keys(person);
delete person[keys[0]];
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: The article you linked to says keys will be in the same order as a for loop. From the [same source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in): “A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order”. You can’t depend on a particular first property of an object.